# swiftyjson bundled file not parsing

Tags: swifty-json

I've validated the coding and everything works up until I get to the actual parsing function I am unsure as to why I am not able to get any of the values in the array of the json file. I have tried multiple methods of getting every object in the array specified string and still nothing. This is the example code I have.

```
  [ { "Attack": 4, "Card Description": "<b>Deathrattle</b>Deal 2 damage to ALL other characters.", "Card Type": "0", "Class": "10", "Cost": 5, "Health": 4, "Name": "Abomination", "Rarity": 3 },
    { "Class": "1", "Name": "Fiery War Axe", "Cost": 2, "Card Type": 2, "Card Description": "", "Rarity": 5 }, ]
```

Comment: The array is actually the top most item level in the construct. It is an array of objects. I am using Power JSON Editor as my JSON Editor.

Comment: That JSON is not valid, the last comma is wrong, before ] (or is that just a mistake from copy/paste?)

Comment: Show your code where you try to parse.

Comment: thats just a mistake from the copy and paste sorry :( I just grabbed the top most items for an example and finished the bracket in a rush.

Comment: if let cards = json["array"].array {
                println(cards)
                for card in cards {
                    if let cardName = card["array"]["Name"].string {
                        println(card)
                }
            }
        }

Comment: this was the coding that I followed it seemed to be the most valid, the problem I am sure is something completely stupid on my part but this part of coding has been extremely frustrating for me. Most things I pick up up real quick but this is just taking me some time...

Comment: I have tried multiple ways adding and removing different paths and nothing seems to work i even tried doing a simple name = json["array"]{"name"].string approach but only turned up nil.

Comment: Just try let name = json["array"][0]["Name"].string - or with your "old" Json, json[0]["Name"].string

Comment: I gave both methods a try yesterday but nothing worked. All that I am getting with both methods is a nil returned when i try to println the name method. The other way just doesn't return anything.

Comment: It will work, there must be some code issues in your file. Ill tried it out (used multiple times too) and works fine.  And you use: let json = JSON(data: dataFromYour file) first? Included SwiftyJSON correct? No other error? Are you able to get ANY value in ANY json file (just make one in the examples of the github page from SwiftyJSON)

Comment: let name = json["array"][0]["Name"].stringValue worked finally on the first object. If i did . string it just turns up nil but the .stringValue function does return the name of the first object in my array. Now that being said how would I pull up all the "Name" from all the objects? Do I have to path to each individual object? I didn't think I should have to but the methods that I researched in that link you showed me all turn the same problem. I am happy I got at least the first object value as that  indicates my .json file is working.

Comment: So you could iterate through json["array"][0].array and read out all values, There are working examples on the github page - just try it out (or upload your project, and i can help you out.

Comment: I have been looking through all the examples but it seems everyone paths to each object individually. I may not be clear enough so I am going to give it another go. Let's say for instance I have 400 objects each with their own "Name" String inside of them. I want to parse all 400 objects for just the "Name" string and nothing else. I thought I shouldn't have to parse each object inside the array individually. I really do appreciate your time with me on this one.

Comment: for obj in json["array"] {
    println(obj["Name"].stringValue)
}                                          this method made sense to me as far as pulling all the "Name" values out but when I went down this route I just received a bunch of errors.

Comment: Finally got what I was looking for. For whatever reason the code I used the first time didn't work but when I quit xcode and restarted my computer it actually worked. The code I used was                                    for (key, subJson) in json["array"] {
                if let Name = subJson["Name"].string { //My functional code here}. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Do you have the patience for another question? It is related to what I want to do with the parsed data. I can actually view it in a tableview but I want to do it efficiently and not have the code bog down the cpu every time.

Comment: If you reload your JSON from an external service, you should store it locally on your device, so that the scrolling performance is fine. You could simple store the json file, or (better) use CoreData (its like an SQLite database)

Comment: It's more on the aspect of displaying the parsed data itself into a tableview. So as I am really new to this side of the coding with json in general I have it stored as a local file but to display it on a tableview cell I have it stored into an array as I was taught to do this. But I saw the cpu spike on the console and I know there must be functional code much better than this.

Comment: I will ask a new question regarding this so I can give you credit for it. I am also going to check off your answer as it lead me to the functional coding I needed to use for my specific function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use:

```
  json["array"].array
```

Your JSON must look like:

```
{
  "array": [
    {
      "Attack": 4,
      "Card Description": "DeathrattleDeal 2 damage to ALL other characters.",
      "Card Type": "0",
      "Class": "10",
      "Cost": 5,
      "Health": 4,
      "Name": "Abomination",
      "Rarity": 3
    },
    {
      "Class": "1",
      "Name": "Fiery War Axe",
      "Cost": 2,
      "Card Type": 2,
      "Card Description": "",
      "Rarity": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Because "array" is a key for an array.

Then you can use: (json is your JSON Array)

```
for obj in json["array"] {
    println(obj["Name"].stringValue)
}
```

Comment: I will give this a try again. I did have my json file setup like this and when I went to use the key value it didn't work. Am I correct in assuming that if I don't assign a specific key it should just be [0]?

Comment: I should be more specific If I don't assign a key value to the primary array it should just be [0] correct? so then my name string would just be let name = [0][0]["Name"].array to get the first objects name value?

Comment: No, it should be json[0]["Name"].string - (just try it out) - but i prefer to create an index here, so for example:  json['items'][0]["Name"].string -> just change "array" to "items" in my example.

Comment: I will try this hopefully tonight I have a wedding to attend for a family member. I will let you know how it goes hopefully all will go well after I make the appropriate changes to the code to make it look like your suggestion. Thanks again!

Comment: I actually gave both methods a try and I am still turning up nil. I am unsure as to why as when I try to println(name) which is the name = json part of the code no matter the sequence or amount of paths I try and use to get it it still pulls a nil. When I println(json) though the full list including all parts properly prints out.